# Help downloading iOS 7 with link that drops

Tags: ios, ipad

I recently purchased an iPad 4 and I have been trying to update to iOS 7 for weeks but the link keeps dropping. What can I do so I can pickup download from where it stopped. My connection is very slow and 1,2 gigs can sometimes take days to download.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the IPSW specific to your device here:

- http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-7-final-ipsw-for-iphone-5-4s-4-ipad-and-ipod-touch-direct-links/

Use iTunes to restore your device using that IPSW (shift-click Restore and select the IPSW).